# How to save matlab figure in different formats, i.e., labels and ticks in vector format but image in bitmap format?

Tags: matlab, bitmap, vector-graphics, save-as

When using `MATLAB` to draw vector graphics, sometimes the content in the image is pretty rich, then if the entire image is saved as a vector image, the file is very large (maybe several tens M).

I want to ask if there is a way to save only the tick numbers and axis labels as vector format, while the complex images in the middle are saved as bitmap.

For Example,

```matlab
[X,Y] = meshgrid(1:0.5:10,1:20);
Z = sin(X) + cos(Y);
C = X.*Y;

figure('Renderer', 'painters')
hs = surf(X,Y,Z,C);
xlabel('\itx \rm(m)');
ylabel('\ity \rm(m)');
zlabel('\itz \rm(m)');
colorbar;
saveas(hs, 'Surface Picture Example', 'emf')
```

which gives the vector format as shown in
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1oFV.jpg)

In this figure, I want to save the tick numbers such as `0, 5, 10` as well as labels such as `x(m)` and `y(m)` to vector format, while saving the surface image as bitmap.

Thanks a lot!